# Declension of "erster" as an adjective

Tags: adjective-ending

As a German native, I'm a bit intimidated by the following sentence, since I didn't study German grammar:

> Er behauptete, *der Welt erster Fallschirmspringer* zu sein.

A friend claimed that it is "der Welt erste Fallschirmspringer" instead. The "erste" loses its "r".

Who is right?

Comment: Wenn du ein deutscher Muttersprachler bist, kannst du deine Frage ruhig auf Deutsch stellen. Mehr als 95% aller Antworten stammen ebenfalls von deutschen Muttersprachlern.

Comment: Most of the page is English, so I just stuck to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right!

The sentence

> Er behauptete, *der Welt* erster Fallschirmspringer zu sein.

possesses a **preposed genitive**, i.e., *der Welt*. Here, the article *der* belongs to *Welt* and not to *Fallschirmspringer*! You can check this by exchanging the masculine noun phrase with a neuter one:

> Er behauptete, *der Welt* erstes Kind zu sein.

The sentences can be transformed into ones with **postposed genitive**, simply by shifting the whole genitiv construction and maintaining the rest—including the strongly declined adjectives *erster* and *erstes*—as it is:

> Er behauptete, erster Fallschirmspringer *der Welt* zu sein.
>   
>   Er behauptete, erstes Kind *der Welt* zu sein.

---

As @guidot hinted in a comment, you can insert an additional article in the sentences with postposed genitive. As a result, the adjectives must be declined weakly (*erste*):

> Er behauptete, **der erste** Fallschirmspringer *der Welt* zu sein.
>   
>   Er behauptete, **das erste** Kind *der Welt* zu sein.

This, however, is not possible when the genitive is preposed:

> <s>Er behauptete, *der Welt* **der erste** Fallschirmspringer zu sein.</s>
>   
>   <s>Er behauptete, *der Welt* **das erste** Kind zu sein.</s>
>
> or
>
> <s>Er behauptete, **der** *der Welt* **erste** Fallschirmspringer zu sein.</s>
>   
>   <s>Er behauptete, **das** *der Welt* **erste** Kind zu sein.</s>

Comment: I also suspect, there is some interference with the straight-forward construction  Er behauptete, der **erste** Fallschirmspringer der Welt zu sein.

Answer (score 7):

Mich den bisherigen Antworten anschließend unterstreiche ich, dass es *erster* heißen muss, als würde man

> Er behauptete, erster Fallschirmspringer der Welt zu sein.

schreiben oder sagen. Ergänzen möchte ich es mit einer Alternative, auf die noch niemand kam:

> Er behauptete, der welterste Fallschirmspringer zu sein.

Ähnlich wie *der Dorfälteste* könnte man von einem *weltersten* sprechen. Allerdings tut das quasi niemand. Man dürfte aber. Es müsste also ein Wort sein.

Comment: Prima Alternative! Ich vermute mal, dass sie einst aus der Verschmelzung des vorangestellten Genitivs mit dem Adjektiv entstanden ist.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your sentence structure to

```
"Er behauptete, der erste Fallschirmspringer der Welt zu sein"
```

you'll see that "der erste Fallschirmspringer" is in the nominative case because it is the subject of the sentence (which is extended by the attributive genitive "der Welt"). If you put the attributive genitive first, the "der" is removed but the case won't change so you have "der Welt erster Fallschirmspringer". ("erster Fallschirmspringer" is still in the nominative case)